# How do I know if a new tag is warranted?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I made a post involving the mist pass and typed in a tag for "mist" but then the confirmation dialog popped up and I had second thoughts because maybe "mist" can be categorized under "render-passes". How specific is too specific? How general is too general?

Comment: Brilliant question! It would be good to revisit this I think (in the past we've often discussed how specific tags should be). To get a rough upper bound for the number of questions which would likely use such a tag, a [search like this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=mist+is%3Aquestion) can be helpful.